# Unable to remove the "SE for Android" application from my account

Tags: support, bug, android-app

In the early days of my smartphone usage, I had installed and authorised the "SE for Android" application, which was the official app for using SE on phone.

Now that the app has been discontinued, and while checking my settings on SE, I noticed that the app was listed as authorised.

When trying to remove the same from my profile settings, the clicking on "Remove" button does nothing. There are no errors reported to the dev console either.

Is the support for app so dead that you can't even revoke the permissions?

The only extension enabled in the browser is [dark reader](https://darkreader.org/).

I tried clicking the remove button from meta.se, as well as my profiles on SO, but same results.

[image]

Comment: I don't think they'll fix it, more likely when the app is 100% dead (i.e. server will shut down and existing apps will stop working) they'll just remove this from all accounts automatically.